# Is a CPU core busy while reading from persistent storage?

Tags: multithreading, file, io, multiprocessing

In-general, when a process thread makes a read system call, the thread's execution is suspended and the reading itself happens (or is scheduled to happen) in the OS kernel. Once the read is complete, the kernel then schedules the suspended thread for continued execution. I understand this part.

My question is, while the kernel is reading from persistent storage (e.g. an HDD or an SSD), is there a CPU core busy orchestrating that read?

I'm asking to help determine the optimum number of threads in my process. For example, if I have a 4-core CPU and one thread in my process is blocking on a read system call, how many other threads could be running in-parallel while waiting for that read to complete? 3? 4? Something more subtle in-between 3 and 4?

Comment: Typical latency of HDD storage is around ... https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 10 milliseconds or kind of 30000000 CPU ticks; SSDs are faster, around 1-0.5 milliseconds or around 1500000-3000000 (at 3 GHz CPU - 3 ticks per ns, 3000 per us, 3 million per ms). So, when file read misses file data already cached in the memory and generate external I/O read, CPU probably will not busy wait for the request and will allow other thread to run.

Comment: Instead of trying to determine the number of threads, use *non-blocking* calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the read does not keep a CPU core busy.

Here's a (very) simplified description of what's going on when you try to read from a drive:

- The application asks the OS to read.
- If reading from a file: the filesystem checks its cache. If the requested data is in the cache, it's returned immediately. If no, the filesystem asks the storage driver to fetch the data from the drive. See next step.
- The storage driver sends a request to the storage device (e.g. a hard drive) to fetch data. This requests is then asynchronously handled by the drive.
- The OS puts the application to sleep (more precisely: the thread that waits for the read).
- ... some time passes ...
- The storage device has finished reading the requested data. It raises an interrupt.
- The OS's/driver's interrupt handler is called, which copies the data into the application's memory.
- The application's blocked thread is unblocked and scheduled for execution.
- The application's thread continues running.

As you can see from this, there is no busy-waiting anywhere. While the application is blocked waiting for the read, the CPU can be used for other tasks (or go idle if there are no other tasks).

**EDIT**: As *osgx* mentioned in a comment, there are exceptions to this. Both the networking and the storage layer, at least in Linux, resort to busy-polling under some circumstances, when it's fast to just block than to continue asynchronously.

Comment: With network drivers there is sometimes temporary interrupt-less busy-waiting mode: [NAPI polling](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/222684748_fig1_Fig-1-NAPI-polling-algorithm) ([sometimes with low-latency](https://lwn.net/Articles/540281/)). For SATA/SAS HDD with 80, 120 or 200 IOPS no such mode is needed, but for modern SSD with more than 10000 IOPS there should be polling mode in driver too (10000 interrupts per second is large number, and 90k for SATA/SAS or 150000 for NVMe is larger).

Comment: @osgx thanks for this additional info. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Rolf, polling is true for some network, and [may be true for some NVMe SSDs  (blk_mq_poll/io_poll_delay)](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lemoal-nvme-polling-vault-2017-final_0.pdf), but only in system-wide view. For single process the single request will not be completed in the short amount of polling time, and it will sleep until interrupt. Only when there are many processes and many requests polling mode may help to lower average latency by skipping interrupt entry/exit or context switch.

Comment: And if that happens, a CPU core is kept busy with spinning for a while, right? Do you have any suggestions how I should rephrase that part of the answer?

Comment: Answer is correct already. Just learning about NVMe polling in Linux. Fast NVMe devices with poll will help for single request too - slide 10,14  http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lemoal-nvme-polling-vault-2017-final_0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Typical latency of HDD storage is around ... 
https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832  Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know
Raw

> ```
> Read 4K randomly from SSD*             150,000   ns      150 us          ~1GB/sec SSD
> Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*     1,000,000   ns    1,000 us    1 ms  ~1GB/sec SSD, 4X memory
> Disk seek                           10,000,000   ns   10,000 us   10 ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
> Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    20,000,000   ns   20,000 us   20 ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
> ```

- For HDD 10 milliseconds or kind of 30000000 CPU ticks;
- For SSDs, which are faster: around 1-0.5 milliseconds or around 1500000-3000000 (at 3 GHz CPU - 3 ticks per ns, 3000 per us, 3 million per ms).

So, when file read misses file data already cached in the memory and generate external I/O read, CPU probably will not busy wait for the request and will allow other thread to run. CPU will be used to generate the I/O request with VFS subsystem and I/O driver. And completed request will (in typical case) generate interrupt to signal driver that required data is loaded to memory.